# Problem with gpio interface raspberry pi b

Tags: processing, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, gpio, motordriver

So I am actually trying to interface my raspberry pi with a motor driver too run two motors using a raspberry pi camera v1.3 but there seems to be some problem related to gpio.

I am using Raspbian so I did try

```
sudo apt-get update
```

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but updating does not seem to help me solve the problem
neither does updating my gpio interface.

Here is a code I am using to light up a led on my board as soon as the camera finds something.

```
import processing.io.*; // use the GPIO library

// store the desired state of the LED in a variable
boolean ledOn = false;

void setup() {
  // set pin 17 as an output:
  GPIO.pinMode(17, GPIO.OUTPUT);
}

void draw() {
  if (ledOn == true) { // If the desired state is on, then:

    // turn the LED on:
    GPIO.digitalWrite(17, GPIO.HIGH);

    // and set the background red:
    background(255, 0, 0);
  }

  else { // otherwise:

    // turn the LED off:
    GPIO.digitalWrite(17, GPIO.LOW);

    // and set the background black:
    background(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

void mouseClicked() {
  // When the mouse is clicked, store the opposite of
  // ledOn into ledOn, which toggles ledOn:
  ledOn = !ledOn;
}
```

The code compiles successfully but it returns a error saying

```
/sys/class/gpio/gpio4/direction: No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE**

Reinstalling the whole operating system from scratch seems to fix the problem.

Comment: Please try post the shortest code necessary to reproduce

Comment: @PLASMAchicken a simple code such as this one (https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/introduction-to-processing/8)  gives the same error i just can't seem to interface with the gpio at all.

Comment: Does that file or directory exist? Sounds like you need to track down what file is expected, and then make sure that file is present.

Comment: @KevinWorkman it seems to be an os related problem, so I just reflashed the whole operating system back and it worked :)

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question.